# Remove list element occur only once

Tags: erlang

I have a list in erlang containing interger values. 
I want to remove values that occur only one time.(Not Duplicates).

```
Input = [1,3,2,1,2,2] 
Output = [1,2,1,2,2]
```

I am newbie to erlang. I have tried an approach to sorting them first using `list:sort()` and then removing a member if the member next to it is the same.
I am having trouble trying to iterate the list. It would be great help if you can show me how I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use map to count values and then filter values which was not present just once.

```
-module(test).
-export([remove_unique/1]).

remove_unique(L) ->
    Count = lists:foldl(fun count/2, #{}, L),
    lists:filter(fun(X) -> maps:get(X, Count) =/= 1 end, L).

count(X, M) ->
    maps:put(X, maps:get(X, M, 0) + 1, M).
```

And test:

```
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> test:remove_unique([1,2,3,3,3,5,5,6,7,7]).
[3,3,3,5,5,7,7]
3> test:remove_unique([1,2,3,3,3,5,5,6,7,8]).
[3,3,3,5,5]
4> test:remove_unique([1,3,2,1,2,2]).        
[1,2,1,2,2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the best solution @Hynek

Comment: Very nice and simplified solution using maps. Just out of curiosity, what is the time complexity of `maps:get`?

Comment: @A.Sarid: O(1) by theory but O(logN) in practice. I haven't heard or seen technology which would have O(1) access time for really unbound K/V storage including a lineary addressed array in memory or memory itself but it would be long discussion why so. So this solution is O(N*logN) if you think about really unbound solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
multiple(L) ->
    M = L -- lists:usort(L),
    [X || X <- L , lists:member(X,M)].
```

Comment: Nice solution but has one flaw, O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: I know, there was no indication about the typical length of the lists, this solution is faster up to 250 elements on my PC, the filter using map then becomes more and more efficient.

Comment: Actually, your solution is pretty smart how it uses as much of Bifs as possible which makes it pretty fast for short lists.

Answer (score 0):

One way for iterating a list (that as a result will return a new list) is using recursion and pattern matching.

After you sort your list you want to iterate the list and to check not only that it is different from the next element, but that there was no other equal elements before it. Consider the list `[3,3,3,5,5]` if you will only check the next element, the last `3` will also be unique and that is incorrect.

Here is a working program, I used a counter to cover the above case as well. See the syntax for using `[H|T]` for iterating over the list. You may see more cases and read more about it [here](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html).

```
-module(test).
-export([remove_unique/1]).

remove_unique(Input) ->
    Sorted = lists:sort(Input),
    remove_unique(Sorted, [], 0).
% Base case - checks if element is unique
remove_unique([H|[]],Output,Count) ->
    case Count of
        0 -> Output;
        _Other -> [H|Output]
    end;
% Count is 0 - might be unique - check with next element
remove_unique([H1|[H2|T]],Output, 0)->
    case (H1 =:= H2) of
        true -> remove_unique([H2|T],[H1|Output],1);
        false -> remove_unique([H2|T],Output,0)
    end;
% Count is > 0 - not unique - proceed adding to list until next value
remove_unique([H1|[H2|T]],Output,Count) ->
    case (H1 =:= H2) of
        true -> remove_unique([H2|T],[H1|Output],Count+1);
        false -> remove_unique([H2|T],[H1|Output],0)
    end.
```

**Test**

```
7> test:remove_unique([1,2,3,3,3,5,5,6,7,7]).
[7,7,5,5,3,3,3]
8> test:remove_unique([1,2,3,3,3,5,5,6,7,8]).
[5,5,3,3,3]
```

Comment: Thanks For you help !

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without disrupting the sequence of the list thus without using sorting ?

Comment: Yes, just iterate the same way and each time check if the element appears again on the list. If it does - add it to the output list, else - don't add.

Comment: @MuhammadSaad: Check out my simple [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38934843/49197).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I'd written when first seeing the question when posted, that uses the same logic as @A.Sarid's recursion/pattern matching answer, except that I use a "Last" parameter instead of the count.

```
-module(only_dupes).

-export([process/1]).

process([]) -> [];
process(L) when is_list(L) ->
  [H|T] = lists:sort(L),
  lists:sort(process(undefined, H, T, [])).

process(Last, Curr, [], Acc)
  when Curr =/= Last ->
  Acc;

process(_Last, Curr, [], Acc) ->
  [Curr | Acc];

process(Last, Curr, [Next | Rest], Acc) 
  when Curr =/= Last, Curr =/= Next ->
  process(Curr, Next, Rest, Acc);

process(_Last, Curr, [Next | Rest], Acc) ->
  process(Curr, Next, Rest, [Curr | Acc]).
```